# Getting dialog state from another component

Tags: reactjs, react-functional-component, fluentui-react, powerapps-modeldriven

I have a PCF which load few components in the same index.ts: main container, aside container and another one container where a dialog component is loaded. This dialog includes a dropdown control which load some items from the index.ts init procedure. Could I get selected values from another componets?

My index.ts:

```
public init(context: ComponentFramework.Context<IInputs>, notifyOutputChanged: () => void, state: ComponentFramework.Dictionary, container: HTMLDivElement) {
    this.container.appendChild(this.containerMain);
    this.container.appendChild(this.containerAside);
    this.container.appendChild(this.containerDialog);
    // actions to populate this.list with WebAPI.retrieveMultipleRecords
    ReactDOM.render(
        React.createElement(Dialog, Object.values(this.list)),
        containerDialog);
...   

public updateView(context: ComponentFramework.Context<IInputs>): void {
    ReactDOM.render(
        React.createElement(Main),
        this.containerMain);

    ReactDOM.render(
        React.createElement(Buttons),
        this.containerAside);

}
```

Dialog component is this [Fluent UI component](https://developer.microsoft.com/es-ES/fluentui#/controls/web/dialog) and must be opened at the component loading.

My question is, could I save the user's chooises from the dialog in order to modify other components with it?

Comment: Use a state store?

Comment: You have to pipe your values down to the components as props, or have to use a `state management library` like recoiljs, redux, context or you can use Hooks for this.

Comment: Or "Lifting state up" https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html